Allure reports showing NAN% and blank data when integrated in azure devops pipeline
I am new to Cypress automation and I am trying to create an azure devops pipeline for calling UI based tests in cypress.
The pipeline is giving success status but the report shows NAN% along with no data.
Below is my pipeline for your reference:
trigger:
- main
pool:
 name: XXXXXXXXX

steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  inputs:
        Contents: '**\*'
        TargetFolder: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
    workingDir: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    workingDir: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
    customCommand: 'install cypress --save-dev'
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    workingDir: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
    customCommand: 'install --save-dev allure-commandline'
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    workingDir: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
    customCommand: 'install --save-dev allure-cypress'
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      echo 'landing in solution folder'
      cd $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
      echo 'run cypress'
      npx cypress run --env allure=true --browser chrome
- task: AllureGenerate@1
  inputs:
     resultsDir: 'allure-results'
     targetDir: 'allure-report/$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    
- task: PublishAllureReport@1
  inputs:
    reportDir: 'allure-report/$(Build.BuildNumber)'

The report that is generated looks like this :

I was expecting the allure report to have details of the tests which ran in the pipeline but no data is appearing.

Maybe you're setting the wrong reportDir in the PublishAllureReport@1 task? Try running the pipeline in Diagnostics mode (tick the lower-left corner checkbox when queuing a new pipeline) and check the logs of the AllureGenerate@1 to find out in which folder are the reports generated.

Based on my test, I can reproduce the same issue with the YAML sample.

The cause of the issue is that the allure-results folder will be generated in the $(build.artifactstagingdirectory). But the AllureGenerate@1 task in the YAML sample is finding the folder in the $(build.sourcesdirectory) by default.
In this case, it will generate an empty allure report if the task can not find the allure-results folder .
To solve this issue, you can change the resultsDir from allure-results to $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\allure-results in AllureGenerate@1 task.
If the allure-results folder is not in the root of $(build.artifactstagingdirectory), you need to add an additional path to the resultsDir field of AllureGenerate@1 task.
For example:
steps:
.....

- task: AllureGenerate@1
  inputs:
     resultsDir: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\allure-results'
     targetDir: 'allure-report/$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    
- task: PublishAllureReport@1
  inputs:
    reportDir: 'allure-report/$(Build.BuildNumber)'

Result:

